# How to refer to files relative to project root in deployment of a database project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project, openrowset

I have a database project in Visual Studio 2010 where in the post-deploy script I want to import the binary data from two files into the database. To that end, I have code very much like the following in a file referenced from the post-deploy script file:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable] ([Column1], [Column2])
SELECT t1.BulkColumn, t2.BulkColumn
FROM 
OPENROWSET(BULK N'$(ProjectDirectory)\Scripts\Post-Deployment\TestData\t1.dat', SINGLE_BLOB) AS t1,
OPENROWSET(BULK N'$(ProjectDirectory)\Scripts\Post-Deployment\TestData\t2.dat', SINGLE_BLOB) AS t2;
```

This *has* worked before. I'm not sure at what point it stopped working, but now, all I seem to get is the error `SQL01262: The variable 'ProjectDirectory' has not been defined` (ironically, with an error location of the post-deploy script itself, row 0 column 0). I dug through the files under the project root and found it kinda-sorta defined in the project file itself, which has the following within the top-level `<Project>` node:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <SqlCommandVariableOverride Include="ProjectDirectory=$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Changing `$(ProjectDirectory)` to `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` in the snippet above changed nothing except the variable name in the error message. The error occurs during the validation stage of deployment, not during deployment itself.

**What is the correct way to, in the post-deploy script, reference files relative to the project's root directory, for including the contents of those files in the database deployment?**

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar situation. The post-deployment script includes another sql file using the sqlcmd

```
:r "..\..\Another.sql"
```

In Another.sql I reference a variable defined in Database.sqlcmdvars and VS was complaining that the variable was not defined. I manually edited the project file. The PropertyGroup element did not contain the child elements DeploymentConfigFile and SqlCommandVariablesFile so I copied them from another PropertyGroup element. I have no idea if this is the correct solution but now the variable can be referenced.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Populate' ">
    <OutputPath>.\sql\Populate\</OutputPath>
    <TargetDatabase>SomeDatabase</TargetDatabase>
    <TargetConnectionString>Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False</TargetConnectionString>
    <DeploymentConfigFile>Properties\Database.sqldeployment</DeploymentConfigFile>
    <SqlCommandVariablesFile>Properties\Database.sqlcmdvars</SqlCommandVariablesFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
```